# Can I generate keystore from jks or pem file

Tags: android-studio, keystore, google-play-console, signed-apk, rsa-key-fingerprint

Hi everyone I got some problems while trying to update my android app:

- So first I lost my keystore password and I solve It by contacting google support and requested to reset It.
- Then after that I got this problem:

"Your Android App Bundle has been signed with the wrong key. Make sure your app bundle is signed with the correct key and try again. The bundle app you imported should normally be signed with the certificate associated with the fingerprint"

so my question is can I use my .pem or keystore.jks that I used to generate another keystore that have the same finger SHA1 that google got to reset my keystorepassword

or is that any other solution please if some one can help

just for clarification this the 2nd release I want to update my app (the App is already in the app store)

Answer (score 1):

If you have reset your upload key, you must have already created a keystore as part of that operation. You should use that keystore to sign your app from now on.

You cannot recreate the keystore from the pem file, but the jks file *is* the keystore, so reference this file in your signing config.

Comment: That's the problem when tried to upload it , it says that the fingerprint sha1 is different

Comment: How can I use jks file as my keystore? because when I tried to put it on my signing it says that the format is incorrect

Comment: I'm confused. On one hand you say you were able to sign it and upload it but the fingerprint is incorrect, but on the other hand you say that the format of the jks is incorrect, if so how could you sign it? Go on the Play Console (page "App Integrity") and check that the SHA1 for the upload key of your app is the same as the one in your keystore. If it's not, then ask Google Play to reset your key with the certificate from the keystore you're using.

Comment: so when I tried to signed with they keystore. txt I got the error of different fingerprint so now I'm trying to sign with .jks I got invalid format

Answer (score 1):

Follow this procedure to generate a new .jks file and then a .pem file which will have the same fingerprint.

First open a terminal at AS and execute command to generate new .jks file:

> keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore_something.jks

Above you can use whatever attribute for alias you want, here is "upload" (note it somewhere). During the execution the terminal will ask you for new passwords, name and all other stuff. These info is going to be written inside your .jks file so write them down also for future reference.

Then you can create the new .pem file that you are going to send to Google Platform for reset:

> keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore_something.jks

Watch out for the alias parameter...you have to use the one as above...you can leave it to "upload".
Then you can send that to Google.

If you want to check the fingerprints of the jks and the .pem file use:

> keytool -list -v -keystore keystore_something.jks -alias upload -storepass inputValue -keypass inputValue

> keytool -printcert -file upload_certificate.pem

You will see that they match.